# Properties of the Complement of a Sumset

Tags: reference-request, additive-combinatorics

Let $(G, +)$ be a finite abelian group.
Let $A, B$ be subsets of $G$.
Then we define the sumset (or Minkowski sum) as:
$$A + B = \{a + b\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$$
Fix a subset $C\subseteq G$.
For any $A\subseteq C$, we can (attempt to) define the *complement* of $A$ (denoted $\overline{A}$) within $C$ as follows:
$$\overline{A} := \arg\max_{A'\subseteq C}(A + A' \subseteq C)$$
This name is meant to contrast with the traditional set complement $A^c$, which can be written (where $\sqcup$ is the disjoint union):
$$A^c := \arg\max_{A'\subseteq C}(A \sqcup A' \subseteq C)$$
Has this notion been introduced before?
If so, have properties of $\overline{A}$ been worked out?
I've tried leafing through some textbooks on Additive combinatorics, but haven't seen anything similar (despite it being a rather naïve notion to introduce).

Comment: +1: interesting question. I'm afraid I don't know the answer, but I think $A' \subseteq A$ should read $A' \subseteq C$ in your equation for $A^c$.

Comment: @RobArthan Good catch, thanks!